# Put a back button to woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to put a back button to the single product page by adding

```
 <button type="button" onclick="history.back();"> Back </button>
```

The problem is that if I put this code in the inspect panel I can easily get it to work but I have no idea where I should put it in my real folder?

Can anyone give me a hint about how to go about this? I have tried to put in the single_product.php file but nothing executes when I do this.

[Here is it shown with the code in the inspect panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LgFE.png)

Comment: Basically, you can customize single product template and add that html code. Here is info: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: I know this. But when I do this, the code do not execute. I have put this button inside the single_product.php but nothing executes when I load the site.

Comment: Then I recommend to show your code form single_product.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you're a bit confused about how WooCommerce template overrides work. Here's some important info you should be aware of:

1. Installing WooCommerce won't modify your theme at all.
2. You shouldn't have a woocommerce/templates/ directory in your theme,
   even if the theme is overriding default WooCommerce templates.
   Rather, you may have a woocommerce/ directory (without the
   templates/ directory).
3. WooCommerce templates are overridden by copying template files from
   `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/xxx.php`to `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/xxx.php`

If you aren't seeing a `woocommerce` directory in your theme, that means that your theme is using the default WooCommerce templates. If you would like to override them, you need to copy the `single_product.php` template from the WooCommerce plugin templates directory into a `woocommerce/` directory within your theme.

More info in the [WooCommerce documentation.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Hey,

I am doing this already. My theme did not have WooCommerce installed, so I have put up a woocommerce/ directory in my theme. 

The code is normally executing perfect when I make changes. It is just this HTML button I can not get working.

Comment: Hi, can you try that code below please, `add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'backbutton', 5);
 function backbutton() {
    echo ' <button type="button" onclick="history.back();"> Back </button>     ';
}` Please notify me what happened.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help so far! Now it shows up actually but it shows up with the button and then the code behind the button 

    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'backbutton', 5); function backbutton() { echo ' BACK  '; }

Comment: I have posted a screenshot in the thread called 'button and code behind'

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding code below for back button.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'backbutton', 5);
function backbutton() {
    echo ' <button type="button" onclick="history.back();"> Back </button> ';
}
```

But I'm not able to click the back button on the mobile version. Is there a solution?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Fix mobile view, add this to additional CSS

```css
[type="button"] {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Disallow unqualified attribute selectors. Unqualified attribute selectors are known to be slow.